# recover text messages

Tags: data-recovery, clockworkmod-recovery, mobile-data, delete

I have an Huawei running the latest Android.  I accidentally deleted some Very important text messages and they haven't been backed up.  Is there anyway I can retrieve them?

Comment: no, not from the device itself. check [notification logs](https://www.howtogeek.com/242073/HOW-TO-VIEW-NOTIFICATIONS-YOUVE-DISMISSED-ON-ANDROID) maybe there is some kind of copy